# the functions of random variables

Tags: self-study, random-variable, density-function

I'm studying for a course and a question came up asking to find multiple functions h such that $Y=h(X)$, where $X \sim$ uniform$[0,1]$ and $Y \sim$ uniform$[-2,8]$.

I understand that $f(x) = 1$ when $0 \leq x \leq 1$ , and $f(y) = 1/10$ when $-2 \leq y \leq 8$. And if I understand correctly they want me to come up with more than one function where I can change $f(x)$ to $f(y)$?

I'm not quite how to do it other than $h(x) = x/10$? Maybe I'm not understanding the question correctly?

Comment: Some help in the right direction. The $h$ function you define produces values in the interval $[0, 0.1]$, not $[-2,8]$... a simple $h$ is e.g. $h(x) = 10x-2$. You have to proof that this is indeed a uniform distribution with support on $[-2,8]$. Then you can go on to find other functions.

Comment: Some possible approaches include (a) exploiting the formulas for computing a PDF or CDF upon a change of variable $h$ (in terms of the absolute value of the derivative of $h$) and (b) using the Probability Integral Transform.  Are you familiar with any of these?

Comment: @whuber I know how to convert a PDF to a CDF but not quite sure what you mean by "change of variable h". I will read up on Probability Integral Transform